# Yarn command "develop" not found

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg

For reference, the goal is to design a blog website on github using .mdx format.

I'm trying to run a prebuilt docker container (I did not compose the image) using an M1 Mac.  For ambiguity's sake - let's say the container image is called "`docker run -it -p "8881:8000" -v "$PWD:/app" "xxxxxxxx/yyy-zzz-purpose-of-container`".  One of the container dependencies is yarn, as can be seen from the output.  Also, the yarn command "develop" is erroring as not found.  Aside from the seemingly inocuous license output, the CLI displays:

`warning package.json: No license field error Command "develop" not found.`

I then tried to run it natively without the docker image as a node.js sequence of commands, and received the same error.

```
nvm install --lts="Gallium"
nvm alias default 'lts/Gallium'
npm install -g npm
npm install -g gatsby-cli
npm install -g yarn

yarn install .

yarn run develop
```

I get the same error as with the container.

Comment: check `package.json` under `script` section, it seems that command `develop` is not defined

Comment: Thank you for this insight.  Is this simply the package in the root directory of the project?

Comment: It's the most common to put `package.json` in root of project

Comment: @kj-crypto the package.json file does have the script:

cat package.json
{
  "private": true,
  "name": ...
  "description": 
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "",
  "license": "Apache 2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby clean && gatsby develop",
    "develop:cypress": "cross-env CYPRESS_SUPPORT=y yarn develop",
    "build:cypress": "cross-env CYPRESS_SUPPORT=y yarn build",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  },

Comment: use `yarn exec develop` or `npm run develop`

Comment: @kj-crypto that worked.  I was running the command in the wrong repo root directory... DOH!  Thank you